# How to get the content of help of argparse, and not to print to console

Tags: python, argparse

I'm work on telegram bot, not the console, need to get the help content to send to user, rather than print out to console, something like this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--aaa", help="help for aaa")
cmd=["-a", "seta"]
args = parser.parse_args(cmd)
helpstring = parser.print_help() # get the help content for furthur process
telegrambot.send(helpstring)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`parser.format_help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.format_help) method:

```
>>> parser.format_help()
'usage: [-h] [-a AAA]\n\noptional arguments:\n  -h, --help         show this help message and exit\n  -a AAA, --aaa AAA  help for aaa\n'
>>> print(parser.format_help())
usage: [-h] [-a AAA]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -a AAA, --aaa AAA  help for aaa
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot